# Get request - formatting JSON file

Tags: api, curl, get

I want to start a curl request from a batch file. The result is a unformatted data file.

```
call curl --request GET  --url "http:*****" --header "Accept: */*"
--header "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" --header "Authorization:****"  --header "Cache-Control: no-cache" --header "Connection: keep-alive" --header "Content-Type: application/json" >****.json
```

Know anyone a solution to get a format json data file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask question,
What OS you are using for curl request?

Depending on the OS, there are many ways that you can reformat the json response.

If it is Ubuntu, you can install "json_reformat" library and use in curl command

i.e. 
`curl ..the url ... | json_reformat`